# Mage_Selenium_Driver::doCommand() should be compatible with that of PHPUnit_Extensions_SeleniumTestCase_Driver

Tags: unit-testing, magento, testing, selenium, automation

I am trying to configure Magento test automation framework on my system.

When I run phpunit in command line, I am getting following error. Same error I am getting while running test in the netbeans.

```
    Strict Standards: Declaration of Mage_Selenium_Driver::doCommand() should 
be compatible with that of PHPUnit_Extensions_SeleniumTestCase_Driver::doCommand() 
in C:\MTAF\taf\lib\Mage\Selenium\Driver.php on line 38
```

..

Fatal error: Call to undefined method PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite::isPublicTestMethod() in C:\MTAF\taf\lib\Mage\Selenium\TestCase.php on line 2502

Can some one please suggest some solution for the same.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the code, this is the change I performed:

```
--- a/framework/Mage/Selenium/TestCase.php
+++ b/framework/Mage/Selenium/TestCase.php
@@ -409,7 +409,7 @@ class Mage_Selenium_TestCase extends PHPUnit_Extensions_SeleniumTestCase
    $testMethods = array();
    $class = new ReflectionClass(self::$_testClass);
    foreach ($class->getMethods() as $method) {
-            if (PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite::isPublicTestMethod($method)) {
+            if ($method->isPublic()) {
        $testMethods[] = $method->getName();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

I was getting this error when running phpunit >= 4.0.  Downgrading to 3.7.x solved it for me.